# Keeping data up to date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, forms-authentication

I'm developing a chat room web app that connects users to limited-size rooms. I'm having trouble figuring out how I should keep my data clean. I'm using forms authentication to keep track of users. With it, I'm able to know when users are offline. In my `User` table, I have `RoomID` to keep track of where the user is. I need to run a check every 5 minutes that finds users that are offline and set any found to an ambiguous room so they don't take up space in a room while offline. It seems like bad practice to include this code in my app because that means it will execute on every single user's instance every 5 minutes. I only need it to execute globally.

As far as I can see, my options are as follows...

1. Make a separate app that checks the DB every 5 minutes and sets all offline users to room 1. The drawback to this approach is that I would need a computer online 100% of the time running the app, always monitoring user status.
2. Include the check in my app. Drawbacks include: multiple unnecessary DB pings, possible crashing due to multiple room deletions at the same time, etc.

Is there another way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just create a sql job to do this? All you need is a stored proc and schedule the job.

Comment: I've never even heard of that (obviously), but I will check into it. Just did a quick search, would I be researching "sql agent job"?

Comment: Yes that is the one.

Comment: Any way other than the SQL agent job? It appears I would have to own SQL Server Enterprise, which is a little out of my budget range.

Comment: You don't need Enterprise for sql jobs. But server agent is not available in sql express.